# xsl - pick up string from second row from sign 20 till sign 30

Tags: xslt

```
<msg>
I told my son, “You will marry the girl I choose.” He said, “NO!” 
I told him, “She is Bill Gates’ daughter.” He said, “OK.” 
I called Bill Gates and said, “I want your daughter to marry my son.” 
Bill Gates said, “NO.” I told Bill Gates, My son is the CEO of World Bank.” Bill Gates said, “OK.” I called the President of World Bank and asked him to make my son the CEO. He said, “NO.” I told him, “My son is Bill Gates’ son-in-law.” He said, “OK.” This is exactly how politics works . . .
</msg>
```

I would like to pick up signs from 10 till 20 from first row
from 9 till 19 from second line and 
from 5 till 15 and from 18 till 21 from third line

so I recive someting like

```
<line1> son, “You </line1>
<line2> im, “She </line2>
<line3> lled Bill Gates d sa</line3>
```

so pick line one string from 10 till 20 include empty - somthing like that in xsl : )
is such think possible ?

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using? -- P.S. Note that the first line in your example contains only a return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **XSLT 2.0**, you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="msg">
    <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(., '&#10;')" />
    <line1>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($lines[1], 10, 10)" />
    </line1>
    <line2>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($lines[2], 9, 10)" />
    </line2>
    <line3>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($lines[3], 5, 10)" />
    </line3>
</xsl:template>
```